# How to access Dropbox events page using API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to access Dropbox's Events page using some API?

We basically need activity of shared folder, but with little more details than by using RSS feed.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to access the Dropbox Events page via the Dropbox API.

UPDATE: There is now an endpoint in the API for shared folder metadata https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shared-folders