# how can i get only modified and new files only from dropbox with dropbox php sdk

Tags: php, dropbox-php

I am using dropbox php sdk to search the files from dropbox with solr. everythig is ok but issue is while i am indexing the files into that it is fetching all the files wit get_files() function .but i want only the modified and new files. Is there any way to do that please help me . I am using the following code to get the files

```
public function GetFiles($dropbox_path='', $recursive=true, $include_deleted=false)
    {
        if(is_object($dropbox_path) && !empty($dropbox_path->path)) $dropbox_path = $dropbox_path->path;
        return $this->getFileTree($dropbox_path, $include_deleted, $recursive ? 1000 : 0);
    }
```

please help , thanx in advance

Comment: Not sure but it seems your can't. You'll have to iterate over all directories to found which files has been modified.

Comment: so is it possible to get only new files or modified files??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : No.

Last modified files is referring to the events page of DropBox, it seems you can't get this info easily.

If you want to know which files has been modified since a date, you will have to iterate over all your directories and files.

Source : [How to access Dropbox events page using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694506/how-to-access-dropbox-events-page-using-api)